# Any way to force webpage to print exactly as it looks in browser?

Tags: printing, background, cross-browser

I am looking for options on how to deal with an issue as I don't think there is an easy fix.

We're dealing with a really stubborn client that doesn't want to accept the fact that browsers don't print css backgrounds by default.

He's convinced that XP running IE 6 & 7 are the most common browsers and we are a bad company for not supporting them. (I've shown him analytics from our typical client's visitors but it hasn't changed his mind). I'm rewriting his site to work on them but am stuck with the print stuff now.

He would like (demand is a more accurate term) to have the page print exactly as it looks on the site as well as them look exactly the same in all operating systems & browsers. I don't think it's feasible to go through and put all the images in the html instead of in the css and I've tried the list-style tip without luck. Lots of the color of the site comes in from background css colors as well.

Is there any other options? Or even suggestions on how to deal with this client?

Comment: Interesting question. I just do print screens using http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/snipping-tool and then print the image.

Comment: Backgrounds are not printed, (I did one workaround once using border-color instead and filled the block.) Other then that, provide a PDF, that is the only way to get printing to work correctly.. And use a css to hide everything for print, and instead show a text on print saying: You must print the PDF instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
<style type='text/css'>
  @import 'whatever.css' screen, print;
</style>
```

Make sure `@import` is above all other CSS tags, and that you target the external stylesheet that you have your CSS for your page on.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach:
I would consider converting the web page to a pdf which you can print instead.
An nice way to do the conversion is through a product called PhantomJS. It's essentially a headless browser that will render the page and convert it to a pdf on the fly. You can integrate by running the PhantomJS server and add a link on the original page to download the pdf.

The pdf will then print the page consistently across all browsers. There is however a decent amount of additional work, so you have to consider if it's a good fit for your needs and timeline... 
Additional complexity with this solution is that you have to host the PhantomJS javascript server somewhere, write a PhantomJS script using the API to convert your page to pdf. 
Pdf and image conversions are relatively easy to do, but you have to also consider authentication if your pages require login. PhantomJS will write the converted file to disk on the server, so you would also have to manage downloads to the user's browser.

All in all it's a good chunk of work, but you might find it interesting to at least learn about it :-).

More info here:
http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: This option looks promising. I will look into it further tomorrow when I'm back at work.

The site is written with our own CMS, when the content is changed will it autogenerate a new pdf per page?

Comment: PhantomJS is a headless browser hosted as a JavaScript server. The quick summary is that you can write a PhantomJS script (or find an existing one as open source). You then pass it the url of your page and it can render the page as a pdf on the fly. There are some things to think about though - authentication for one. If your page is behind a login page you will have to deal with the authentication issue inside PhantomJS. I would read about it to see if it will meet your needs. In any event it's a pretty cool open source project.